# Dashed version of \boxed

Tags: equations, boxes

Is there an easy way of putting an equation inside a dashed box?

Ideally similar to `\boxed` from amsmath. The output should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the  small `dashbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dashbox}
\newcommand\dboxed[1]{\dbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{document}

 \[ \dboxed{t\cdot u}\iff\dboxed{t} * \dboxed{u}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to let the dashed box in the same line be of the same height automatically?

Comment: Oh I figured it out, adding `\strut` in the `\dbox{...}` worked fine.

Comment: Yes, and something like  `\vphantom{t}`, in case of a more  complex situation,  could be useful, if `strut` is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for this easy and straightforward hit. I used it right now. ++

Comment: Sorry for asking so late about this topic! Can we rig the code to include text coloring, like in the answers below?

Answer (score 6):

A possibility with `tcolorbox` (Description below)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\tcbox[colback=white,boxrule=0pt,enhanced jigsaw,borderline horizontal={1pt}{0pt}{dashed},borderline vertical={1pt}{0pt}{dashed}]{$E=mc^2$}
\end{document}
```

**Easier version**

`tcolorbox` provides nice features for boxes and frames etc. I've defined a `\dashedbox` command, that has a dashed frame of `1pt` width and white background (colback=white), the usual frame is not drawn (`boxrule=0pt`). In order to provide equal heights, a equal height group is used.

All settings can be overruled by using the optional parameter of `\dashedbox` (as have been done for the second example!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\dashedbox}[1][]{equal height group=dashedbox,
  nobeforeafter,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  borderline horizontal={1pt}{0pt}{dashed},
  borderline vertical={1pt}{0pt}{dashed},
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\dashedbox{$E=mc^2$} \dashedbox[colback=yellow]{$E^2=(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Next update**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\dashedbox}[1][]{
  math upper,
  baseline=0.4\baselineskip,
  equal height group=dashedbox,
  nobeforeafter,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  boxsep=0pt,
  top=2pt,
  bottom=2pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  borderline horizontal={0.5pt}{0pt}{dashed},
  borderline vertical={0.5pt}{0pt}{dashed},
  drop lifted shadow,
  #1
}

\begin{document}
Einstein said: $\dashedbox{E=mc^2} \; \dashedbox[colback=yellow]{E^2=(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It doesn't quite work as I was hoping that it would. It doesn't work in inline math mode, and the boxes have very large margins. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: @MathiasVorreiterPedersen: The margins can be changed easily. I look for the inlinestuff.

Comment: @MathiasVorreiterPedersen: See the update please -- the spacings of the margins can be set with `top=...` etc.